# lost in translation: " changed to

Tags: files, editors, text

A script to delete a large number of directories, on a NAS, is of the syntax:

```
rm -rf "directory1 to be deleted"

rm -rf "directory2 to be deleted"

rm -rf "directoryN to be deleted"
```

The script is created on a Sublime text editor as go.sh to a SAMBA share.  rm -rf "directory to be deleted"  The NAS's vi shows the quotation mark is placed with ... and a ^m is appended to each line.  Attempts to run the script fail.

Is there either:

1) a setting in gedit or or sublime to correctly save it the file for Unix

2) or is there a simple VI search and replace ... with a quotation mark? and remove ^m

VI attempts to search and replace [failed using this article](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-unix-vim-find-replace-text-string-words/)

Comment: In sublime, look at the **View->Line Endings** setting. Does it say **Windows** or **UNIX**?

Comment: Could you please clarify whether the problem is only the ^M at the end of the line? Your title and most of your explanation are incomprehensible. `"` changed to what? What does “the quotation mark is placed with ...” mean?

Answer (score 2):

The `^M` is called CR (Carriage Return), it is part of the DOS style line ending -- CR-LF (Carriage Return - Line Feed).

If you want to convert all DOS style endings to Unix style (LF) i.e. remove all CR (`^M`) using `vi`, in normal mode of `vi` do:

```
:set ff=unix
```